# Finding coefficient of a specific term using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find coefficient of xy using sympy. This is the program.

```
import sympy as sp
fro sympy import Poly
from sympy.abc import x, y
x,y,xy=sp.symbols('x,y,xy')
K=Poly(x**2 + 5*xy + 1).coeff(xy)
print K
```

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sympy as sp

from sympy.abc import x, y
x,y,xy=sp.symbols('x,y,xy')
expression = x**2 + 5*xy + 1
print expression.coeff(xy)
```

Note that this is probably not what you want. You're not looking for a symbol `xy` but for the coefficient with the crossterm of symbols `x` *and* `y`. You should therefor change the expression to:

```
expr = x**2 + 5*x*y+1
expr.coeff(y).coeff(x)
```